# How to build call hierarchy for lombok generated method in intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Given an example:

```
@Data
public VO {
    private String item;
}
```

How to build call hierarchy for the `getItem()`?

I know there is a cumbersome path :open Structure, then find the method, then build hierarchy. Is there more efficient path or plugin?

Answer (score 15):

you can open the "stucture view" this should display the generated methods. If not you maybe need to install the lombok plugin.

In the structure view select the method `getItem()` and press the short cut for the call hierarchy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) and the call hierarchy for the selected method will open up.

Comment: `Strg` means `Ctrl`